# why is my this simple selenium code isn't working?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Actually it only opens youtube but don't type anything and search**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

searchArea = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
searchArea.send_keys('Sujeet Gund')

searchButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')
searchButton.click()
```

Comment: Did you get any errors? Did you check that selenium actually found the DOM elements you were expecting it to?

Answer (score 0):

Try `//input[@id="search"]` instead.

------------------ updated below ------------------

Well, I guess you had copied wrong xpath. Maybe you might just copied the wrapper(or container) not the exact input field.

This solution using specific tag `input` makes selenium easier to find the element. But be careful not to use when there're more than one element with the same xpath.

Plus, I recommend you to use in this way

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


SERVICE = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
OPTIONS = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=SERVICE, options=OPTIONS)
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

searchArea = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//input[@id="search"]')
searchArea.send_keys('Sujeet Gund')
```

because currently some functions in `selenium` are deprecated.

Comment: It actually works! Thanks sir but how could you get it, I mean I tried a lot, always copied correct x path but still code wasn't working! Again thanks for help!

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_